# perl - regular expression - match case

Tags: regex, perl

Hi
I have some file that looks like this:

```
some row
/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5  *.kuku.* noku
/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5  *.kuku noku 
another row
another row
```

if first line is absent I need to add it, if second line is absent I need to add only second line

I wrote regular expressions , but they are not really works:

```
if ($line =~ /(\*\.kuku\.\*\b)/) {do something}

if ($line =~ /(\*\.kuku\b)/) {do something else}
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\b` only matches on word boundaries. `\*\.kuku\.\*\b` will never match because `*` is not a word character.

You could change it to `\s` so you match a whitespace.  `\*\.kuku\.\*\s`